# Queria saber porque nao le as funçoes na tela

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { 
char titulo; 
char autor; 
float preco; 
} livro ;

livro definelivro(char titulo, char autor, float preco){
    
    livro l;
    l.titulo = titulo;
    l.autor = autor;
    l.preco  = preco;
    return l;
}

void mostrarnatela(livro l){
    printf("titulo: %c  autor: %c  preco: %f\n", l.titulo, l.autor, l.preco);
}

int main(){
    
    livro livro1;
    livro1 = definelivro("Crime e Castigo", "Dostoievski", 59.00);
    mostrarnatela(livro1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: que significa "ler as funções na tela"? Você declarou `titulo` e `autor` como `char`, uma única letrinha. Mas chamou a função passando por exemplo _"Crime e Castigo"_ que é `const char[]`. Eis o crime e o castigo: o compilador não aceitou.

Answer (score 1):

Suas funções estão sim sendo lidas e estão funcionando, apenas a chamada da sua função **definelivro**, na *function* **main**, que não está correta para o que você definiu no seu programa

Você definiu no inicio da sua **struct**?

```
char titulo; 
char autor;
```

se você chamar sua função enviar um char onde você declarou seu programa funciona perfeitamente:

```
    livro1 = definelivro('C', 'D', 59.00);
```

Lembre-se de usar aspas simples :) na definição do char

Usando esta chamada de função a resposta será:

```
    titulo: C  autor: D  preco: 59.000000
```